# Get 'ArgumentError' with Chef-client and recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to run follow Chef recipe with chef-client, my recipe is:

```
require 'chef/provisioning/docker_driver'
machine 'wario' do
    recipe 'openssh::default'
    machine_options :docker_options => {
      :base_image => {
          :name => 'ubuntu',
          :repository => 'ubuntu',
          :tag => '14.04'
      },
      :command => '/usr/sbin/sshd -p 8022 -D'
    }
```

but when execute that recipe (and any one) get this:

```
[2016-01-25T09:22:03-05:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
[2016-01-25T09:22:03-05:00] WARN: No cookbooks directory found at or above current directory.  Assuming /home/rizotas/Documents/safari.
Starting Chef Client, version 12.6.0
resolving cookbooks for run list: []
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
Compiling Cookbooks...
[2016-01-25T09:22:05-05:00] WARN: Node myHost has an empty run list.
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: @recipe_files::/home/rizotas/Documents/safari/ssh.rb
  * machine[wario] action converge
    - update node wario at chefzero://localhost:8889
    -   update normal.chef_provisioning.reference.allocated_at from "2016-01-25 14:18:49 UTC" to "2016-01-25 14:22:05 UTC"
    -   add normal.chef_provisioning.reference.docker_options.base_image = {:name=>"ubuntu", :repository=>"ubuntu", :tag=>"14.04"}
    -   add normal.chef_provisioning.reference.docker_options.command = "/usr/sbin/sshd -p 8022 -D"
    -   remove normal.chef_provisioning.reference.docker_options.base_image
    -   remove normal.chef_provisioning.reference.docker_options.command
    -   update run_list from ["recipe[openssh::default]"] to ["recipe[openssh::default]", "recipe[openssh::default]"]
    - update node wario at chefzero://localhost:8889
    -   add normal.chef_provisioning.reference.docker_options.base_image = {:name=>"ubuntu", :repository=>"ubuntu", :tag=>"14.04"}
    -   add normal.chef_provisioning.reference.docker_options.command = "/usr/sbin/sshd -p 8022 -D"
    -   remove normal.chef_provisioning.reference.docker_options.base_image
    -   remove normal.chef_provisioning.reference.docker_options.command
    -   update run_list from ["recipe[openssh::default]"] to ["recipe[openssh::default]", "recipe[openssh::default]"]
    - update node wario at chefzero://localhost:8889
    -   add normal.chef_provisioning.reference.docker_options.base_image = {:name=>"ubuntu", :repository=>"ubuntu", :tag=>"14.04"}
    -   add normal.chef_provisioning.reference.docker_options.command = "/usr/sbin/sshd -p 8022 -D"
    -   remove normal.chef_provisioning.reference.docker_options.base_image
    -   remove normal.chef_provisioning.reference.docker_options.command
    -   update run_list from ["recipe[openssh::default]"] to ["recipe[openssh::default]", "recipe[openssh::default]"]
    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `converge` on resource 'machine[wario]'
    ================================================================================
    
    ArgumentError
    -------------
    invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
    
    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /home/rizotas/Documents/safari/ssh.rb
    
      2: machine 'wario' do
      3:    recipe 'openssh::default'
      4:    machine_options :docker_options => {
      5:      :base_image => {
      6:          :name => 'ubuntu',
      7:          :repository => 'ubuntu',
      8:          :tag => '14.04'
      9:      },
     10:      :command => '/usr/sbin/sshd -p 8022 -D'
     11:    }
     12: end
    
    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /home/rizotas/Documents/safari/ssh.rb:2:in `from_file'
    
    machine("wario") do
      action [:converge]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      chef_server {:chef_server_url=>"chefzero://localhost:8889", :options=>{:client_name=>"myHost", :signing_key_filename=>nil, :api_version=>"0"}}
      driver "docker"
      machine_options {:docker_options=>{:base_image=>{:name=>"ubuntu", :repository=>"ubuntu", :tag=>"14.04"}, :command=>"/usr/sbin/sshd -p 8022 -D"}}
      declared_type :machine
      cookbook_name "@recipe_files"
      recipe_name "/home/rizotas/Documents/safari/ssh.rb"
      run_list_modifiers [#<Chef::RunList::RunListItem:0x007f087ca79528 @version=nil, @type=:recipe, @name="openssh::default">]
    end
    

Running handlers:
[2016-01-25T09:22:07-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2016-01-25T09:22:07-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 04 seconds
[2016-01-25T09:22:07-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/rizotas/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-01-25T09:22:07-05:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-01-25T09:22:07-05:00] ERROR: machine[wario] (@recipe_files::/home/rizotas/Documents/safari/ssh.rb line 2) had an error: ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
[2016-01-25T09:22:07-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I don't know why that `ArgumentError`.
Ruby syntax is OK.
Ruby version 1.8.7
Chef version 12.5.1

How I can solve it?

Thanks :)

## Updates:

### 1:

I have tried with Ruby 1.9, Ruby 2.1.7 and Ruby 2.0.0

### 2:

`chef-stacktrace.out` file:

```
Generated at 2016-01-25 11:43:14 -0500
ArgumentError: machine[wario] (@recipe_files::/home/rizotas/Documents/safari/creating-containers/create-containers.rb line 4) had an error: ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sys-proctable-1.0.0-universal-linux/lib/linux/sys/proctable.rb:137:in `split'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sys-proctable-1.0.0-universal-linux/lib/linux/sys/proctable.rb:137:in `block in ps'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sys-proctable-1.0.0-universal-linux/lib/linux/sys/proctable.rb:114:in `foreach'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sys-proctable-1.0.0-universal-linux/lib/linux/sys/proctable.rb:114:in `ps'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-docker-0.7/lib/chef/provisioning/docker_driver/docker_transport.rb:230:in `using_boot2docker?'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-docker-0.7/lib/chef/provisioning/docker_driver/docker_transport.rb:193:in `make_url_available_to_remote'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-1.5.1/lib/chef/provisioning/machine/basic_machine.rb:75:in `make_url_available_to_remote'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-1.5.1/lib/chef/provisioning/convergence_strategy/precreate_chef_objects.rb:32:in `setup_convergence'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-1.5.1/lib/chef/provisioning/convergence_strategy/install_cached.rb:47:in `setup_convergence'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-1.5.1/lib/chef/provisioning/machine/basic_machine.rb:17:in `setup_convergence'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-provisioning-1.5.1/lib/chef/provider/machine.rb:58:in `block in <class:Machine>'
(eval):2:in `block in action_converge'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/provider.rb:360:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/provider.rb:360:in `compile_and_converge_action'
(eval):2:in `action_converge'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/provider.rb:144:in `run_action'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource.rb:596:in `run_action'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/runner.rb:74:in `run_action'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/runner.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/runner.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/runner.rb:106:in `block in converge'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:83:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:81:in `execute_each_resource'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/runner.rb:105:in `converge'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:658:in `block in converge'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:653:in `catch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:653:in `converge'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:692:in `converge_and_save'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/client.rb:271:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:261:in `block in fork_chef_client'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:249:in `fork'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:249:in `fork_chef_client'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:215:in `block in run_chef_client'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:203:in `run_chef_client'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:413:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:403:in `loop'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:403:in `interval_run_chef_client'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:393:in `run_application'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/lib/chef/application.rb:58:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/chef-12.6.0/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Check that: `(@recipe_files::/home/rizotas/Documents/safari/ssh.rb line 2) had an error: ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` (maybe there's some invisible special char)

Comment: I tried with https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning-docker/blob/master/test/integration/cookbooks/docker-tests/recipes/create-containers.rb and get same error

Comment: Can you take a look at the `/home/rizotas/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out` file and see if there is some more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chef `12.5.1` requires Ruby 2 or higher](https://rubygems.org/gems/chef/versions/12.5.1).

[Ruby 1.8.7 reached EOL long ago](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/07/01/eol-for-1-8-7-and-1-9-2/).

Try upgrading your Ruby version.

#### Update after reading your `chef-stacktrace.out` output:

[The following code from `sys-proctable` gem](https://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable/blob/sys-proctable-1.0.0/lib/linux/sys/proctable.rb#L137) seems to be the problem:

```ruby
IO.read("/proc/#{file}/environ").split("\0").each{ |str|
  key, value = str.split('=')
  struct.environ[key] = value
}
```

Some process has invalid UTF-8 chars in its environment.

There is a related issue here: [djberg96/sys-proctable#19](https://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable/issues/19). In that case it was related to the [`dovecot/imap` process `environ` file filled with `0xab` chars](https://github.com/dovecot/core/blob/2.2.20/src/lib/process-title.c#L17). Maybe you are having the same problem with Dovecot or other process that behaves similarly.

They fixed it setting the default external encoding:

```ruby
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::ASCII_8BIT
```

I recommend you to try to stop this process or maybe to fix its environment if possible.

Based on [@WattsInABox answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34997196/3284723), you can search the `environ` files using `ag`:

`# ag "[\x80-\xFF]" /proc/*/environ`

Another possible approach is to [open an issue in the `sys-proctable` gem](https://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable/issues/new).

Comment: OK. I updated the answer after reading the stacktrace output.

Comment: add `Encoding.default_external = Encoding::ASCII_8BIT` to recipe did solve the error... but is a solution awful. Thanks @zuazo

Answer (score 0):

I double-checked your output for UTF-8 characters and found none. So, as was said in a comment and given the stack trace, you have some UTF-8 character(s) in your ssh.rb (inside your chef repo- `home/rizotas/Documents/safari/ssh.rb`). Is that a file you wrote b/c it sounds like one of the files that's normally included in chef?

I'm not entirely sure it's related to your ruby version, although I guess it could be. The thing is, chef is bundled with standalone ruby now so I'm doubting that's it.

Things I would try, in no particular order:

1. Update ruby just b/c it's easy with things like RVM and like @zuazo said, 1.8 is EOL
2. Run `ag` (the silver searcher) on the ssh.rb to make sure there's no UTF-8 characters in it https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher

   ag "[\x80-\xFF]" ssh.rb
3. Double check for bugs in the OpenSSH cookbook online to make sure this isn't a known issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the ChefDK installers for your workstation. We do not support installing via gems anymore for general usage (read: it works and will continue to work, but you need to handle getting your environment set up correctly).